# Hibernate Composite key with "key-many-to-one" relationship loading performance

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading, hibernate-mapping, many-to-one

I have 2 classes, Student and Course, which become a composite key for a third class, Grade.

```
<class name="Grade" table="grade" lazy="true">
    <composite-id>
        <key-many-to-one class="Student" name="student" column="student_id" lazy="false" />
        <key-many-to-one class="Course" name="course" column="course_id" lazy="false" />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="score" column="score" type="integer" />
</class>
```

If I run a detached criteria query to let's say get all the student grades from a course.

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass( Grade.class );
dc.add( Property.forName( "course" ).eq( course ) );
dc.setFetchMode( "student", FetchMode.JOIN );
List< Grade > grades = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria( dc );
```

I notice the Student object is lazy loaded individually for each row during the .list() process even though the main query is loading the student object as well.  It seems to be some sort of key processing that doesn't even take into account batch size settings (I have dynamic batching set to 50 batch items).  I have found an ugly work around.

```
<class name="Grade" table="grade" lazy="true">
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name="studentId" column="student_id" />
        <key-property name="courseId" column="course_id" />
    </composite-id>
    <many-to-one class="Student" name="student" column="student_id" lazy="false" insert="false" update="false" />
    <many-to-one class="Course" name="course" column="course_id" lazy="false" insert="false" update="false" />
    <property name="score" column="score" type="integer" />
</class>
```

and modifying the Grade class to include those ids. Is there a better way? I do  want the student & course objects available (lazy loaded). Using hibernate 5.2.6.